# Shopify - find a product ID in array

Tags: arrays, shopify

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to find out if a product has been added to the cart, on the cart page. So if the cart array contains a specific ID, then return TRUE or FALSE.

Any assistance will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify has an Ajax API. They also provide a full Javascript library you can freely pillage for code. In that code is a perfect example of getCart() which returns the cart contents. You are then free to check for your specific product ID by examining the contents of the cart.